# Editing facebook's page like code

Tags: css, facebook, html

Hi I have a small problem:

[image]

The text of the page makes the like area too big, so I have a few questions:

Can I edit the text displayed somehow?
Can I NOT show the text?
Can I enable/disable the page image?

Thank you kindly.

Comment: facebook like code documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/ does not contain neither image nor page name. can you provide us which code outputs that screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

You can *just* have the like button with this code:

`<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.YourLinkHere.com" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true">`

Or link whatever you want to "like" with this: http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.YourLinkHere.com&width&layout=button&action=like&show_faces=true&share=true&height=80&appId=180444915344990

Check out https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/ to easily design your like button just the way you want with your photos/text/buttons/etc.